# sql SELECT returns a string in an array, the return_format is set to "string" tho. Sinatra

Tags: sql, ruby, sinatra

I'm currently working on a very basic login system, for a Web development school project. My Problem is, that both variables have the same values but their data-types are different, so the if block does not execute the code for the "true" condition. I set the return_format to "string" but i still get a string in an array. I also already tried to convert both variables into a string(.to_s), but that didn't helped me at all.

Here is the code:

```
pass = use_database "EMTippspiel", :return_format => "string" do |db|
    sql = "SELECT Passwort FROM user WHERE Benutzername = '" + username + "';"
    db.execute sql
end

if params[:password].to_s == pass
    use_database "EMTippspiel" do |db|
        sql = "UPDATE user SET Online = 'true', IP = '" + ip + "' WHERE Benutzername = '" + username + "';" 
        db.execute sql
    end
    redirect to("/hauptseite")
else
    puts "="*80            #for debugging
    p username
    p params[:password] 
    p pass  
    puts "="*80
    @success = false
    redirect to("/anmeldung")
end
```

This is what the console window prints out:

```
======================================================
"Jemin"
"1965"
[["1965"]]
======================================================
```

found the solution, pass was actually an array, so the resolution is:

```
if params[:password].to_s == pass[0][0]
```

Comment: Try replace `puts` with `p` to see if there are any invisible characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but why is pass a string in an array and not just a string?

Comment: nvm. i just found the solution, thanks again!

Comment: The outer array means you may have multiple results from one query. The inner array means one result can have multiple columns. Your query is just a special case that returns one result with one column.

Comment: By the way, concatenating strings is very unsafe to prepare SQL statement because it introduces the exploit of SQL injection attack.

Comment: oh thanks, didn't know that. It's just an school project, but i'll keep it in mind :)